# Yet Another Rails Assocation question

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, associations

I've been digging but I cannot find an answer that makes sense to me.  I have a single "groups" table that is simply an id and a name.  I have other tables that use these groups in various ways.

```
GROUPS {id, name}
INCIDENTS {id, reportedby_group_id, assignee_group_id, resolving_group_id}
```

I have my models setup thusly:

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :incidents
end
class Incident < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :reportedby_group, :class_name => 'Group', :foreign_key => 'reportedby_group_id'
    belongs_to :resolving_group, :class_name => 'Group', :foreign_key => 'resolving_group_id'
    belongs_to :assignee_group, :class_name => 'Group', :foreign_key => 'assignee_group_id'
end
```

What I would like to do is query all incidents that contain certain "Resolving Group", "Assignee Groups", etc, separately, such as:

```
Incident.joins(:resolving_group).where(:resolving_group => {:name => groups(arr)})
```

However, when I try to execute the above query, it fails to associate the Group.name to the resolving group, it prduces the following query:

```
SELECT `incidents`.* FROM `incidents` INNER JOIN `groups` ON `groups`.`id` = `incidents`.`resolving_group_id` WHERE `resolving_group`.`name` IN (
```

When I am looking for something like this:

```
SELECT `incidents`.* FROM `incidents` INNER JOIN `groups` ON `groups`.`id` = `incidents`.`resolving_group_id` WHERE `group`.`name` IN (
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Incident.joins(:resolving_group).where('group.name' => groups)
```

Not sure why it did not occur to me before.